# Creating a btrfs subvolume mounted under another file system

Tags: btrfs

At the moment I have a / partition with btrfs and /home partition with xfs. I would like to take advantage of btrfs snapshots for certain directories under /home, e.g. /home/robert/.wines . Apparently this doesn't work out of the box:

```
 # btrfs subvolume create /home/robert/.wines
 Create subvolume '/home/robert/.wines'
 ERROR: cannot create subvolume  - Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Is there a way to create a subvolume under /home, which is not a btrfs mount?

Comment: Can i ask you a question? Why you did this little "mess" with your filesystem mixing up xfs with btrfs? Why not create everything inside btrfs with subvolumes to achieve and use all the features of this filesystem? Cheers :)

Comment: @nwildner - two reasons. 1) it was the openSUSE recommended layout. 2) I have files which don't necessarily mix well with BTRFS and COW - namely virtual machines

Comment: Fair enough. However, one of the extended attributes of btrfs is actually disable COW. It can be done with `chattr` on a directory, or during the mount of a subvolume - http://ram.kossboss.com/btrfs-disabling-cow-file-directory-nodatacow/ - https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Mount_options. The `nodatacow` mount option on a `/home` subvolume could be enough for your needs ;). Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the documentation:

> Although in btrfs, subvolumes/snapshots are treated as directories, only subvolume/snapshot can be the source of a snapshot, snapshot can not be made from normal directories.

Since your `/home` dir is not a subvolume neither a snapshot, it will not be possible to create a snapshot of anything inside of it.

**Link:**

- [btrfs-subvolume - Documentation](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs-subvolume)